# Embed mymaps on website with possibility to see current position on mobile

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to embed "my maps" to my website using iframe, but I want to let my clients to open that map in a new window and see their location on it.

If I open my map in edit mode on my phone: www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=*** I see my position, if I change the mode to "view" it stops tracking my location.

Is there a way to open the big map and to see the current position? It's very useful... Maybe there is another way to embed it...

Answer (score -1):

Based on the documentation

url: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/intro?hl=en

it seems that it is not possible to get the current location (position of the client) using the parameters which go along with the url. This means that you can not use iframe and embed google maps inside it to get your current position.

However, you can still use geolocation and program it to get the user current position on the map,

url (code included in the link): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

Bare in mind that the google map API will always ask you the permission to access data in order to locate you.

Comment: Bad, I want to see my position on a big map, and in edit mode it works, I don't understand this decision of google map team :/

Comment: Well, maybe there is a workaround but you would have to spend some good time to see how to make it.